# Topos as the category of sheaves on a site and topos as a full category with geometric morphisms.

Tags: topos-theory

I'm not positive where to start contrasting topoi as the categories of sheaves on a site with topoi as full categories with geometric morphisms. The former has objects which I know are able to be "stacks" or "2-sheaves" which are sheaves with a value in $\mathcal{Cat}$. The latter doesn't apparently have to do with the sheaves anymore.... what are some ways they are alike please?

Comment: What is "full categories with geometric morphisms"? Is it a phrase you made up yourself?

Comment: I didnt make up anything by myself I was trying to distinguish between what a topos is that is a/the category of sheaves on a site, (i) in "sketches of an elephant" and the topos that is the full category with power objects (ii) in "sketches of an elephant."

Comment: Please use the words as you found them in your references. Are you translating them from English into your own language and then back again or something? I can tell you that "full category" is not a standard phrase.